# how to find VM ip from host , virsh net-dhcp-leases gives empty output

Tags: virtual-machine

how to find VM ip from host , virsh net-dhcp-leases gives empty output.

tried with domiflist and find the ip for first VM ID and rest of the VM's unable to find the IP address.

Please help

Thanks
Jaychandran S

Answer (score 0):

```
virsh net-list
```

Based on the output, get the network name. Assuming it's **default**

```
virsh net-dhcp-leases default
```

You should see your VM's IP listed

Comment: virsh net-dhcp-leases default this command gives empty output

Comment: and what does the previous command give